# Pig Join by using OR conditional operator throws error

Tags: join, apache-pig

```
child = load 'file_name' using PigStorage('\t') as (child_code : chararray, child_id : int, child_precode_id : int);
parents = load 'file_name' using PigStorage('\t') as (child_id : int, child_internal_id : chararray, mother_id : int, father_id : int);
joined = JOIN child by child_id, parents by child_id;
mainparent = FOREACH joined GENERATE child_id as child_id_source, child_precode_id, child_code;
store parent into '(location of file)' using PigStorage('\t');
childfirst = JOIN  mainparent by (child_id_source), parents by (mother_id OR father_id);
firstgen = FOREACH childfirst GENERATE child_id, child_precode_id, child_code;   
store firstgen into 'file_location' using PigStorage('\t');
```

Getting the following error when I use the OR condition:

> ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error
>   during parsing. Pig script failed to parse:
>   NoViableAltException(91@[]) Failed to parse: Pig script failed to
>   parse: NoViableAltException(91@[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below syntax is incorrect,there is no conditional join in Pig

```
childfirst = JOIN  mainparent by (child_id_source), parents by (mother_id OR father_id);
```

If you would like to join a relation with one key with another relation on 2 keys then create two joins and union the dataset.Note that you might have to distinct the resulting relation.

```
childfirst = JOIN  mainparent by (child_id_source), parents by (mother_id);
childfirst1 = JOIN  mainparent by (child_id_source), parents by (father_id);
childfirst2 = UNION childfirst,childfirst1;
childfirst3 = DISTINCT childfirst2;
firstgen = FOREACH childfirst3 GENERATE child_id, child_precode_id, child_code;   
store firstgen into 'file_location' using PigStorage('\t');
```

Comment: That works, it also solves the problem of getting duplicates, Thanks